# Modify T3 Bulb for a T4 Socket

Tags: electrical, led

I messed up and got G8 T3 LED Bulbs to replace G8 T4 Halogens.  The bulbs work just fine in the sockets except the pins are smaller than the socket was designed for (T4) and don't stay well.  They were in the socket and on for about 24 hours straight working fine until they fell out.  Is it safe to modify these, say cut the larger pins off the T4s and solder them on the T3s or something else to make them fit better?  Just trying to be frugal and not buy more things if it's safe to do so.

Comment: Why don't you return the bulbs, and get the proper ones?

Answer (score 1):

It is not safe to operate the bulbs in the wrong sized socket. The loose connection can produce arcing which will cause heating of the connection and could very well lead to fire.

There really is not a practical way to safely replace the pins either. Even though some LED models may appear that it would be possible to solder on different pins I would advise against it. And it is likely that you would either damage the pin attachment points or that obtaining the correct materials ends up costing nearly as much as just getting the proper bulbs.

Safety should not be supplanted by frugality. Get the proper product for the application. Return the product if possible as suggested by Tester101 in the comments. If not returnable then eat up your mistake as a bad investment and learn from it to look more closely at what you select for purchase.

Comment: I wanted to leave an outcome response.  It turns out I did in fact have the correct bulbs.  I compared the pins on the old halogen and the new LED bulbs side by side and found the new LED bulbs' pins were a little longer.  This coupled with the fact that the LED bulbs were surrounded by a clear gelatin type material prevented the bulbs from completely seating inside the socket.  This is why they were loose.  I snipped the pins to the same length as the halogens and trimmed the clear gelatin as needed to allow the bulbs to solidly seat and everything seems correct now.